# R: Pattern matching one column to a json string stored in another column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of untidy data: `TX_JAN_2019_DF`

This dataframe contains a columns `TX_JAN_2019_DF$AREA` (type: numeric) and `TX_JAN_2019_DF$DEVICE_HOME_AREA` (type: character)

`TX_JAN_2019_DF$AREA[1]` produces:[1] 481210216382

`TX_JAN_2019_DF$DEVICE_HOME_AREA[1]` produces a sample of the string (for this benefit of this post, this output is greatly reduced):

`"{\"481210216382\":307,\"481210216371\":50,\"481210216381\":43,\"481130137213\":35,\"481210216373\":27,\"481130137222\":21,\"481210216154\":21,\"481210216152\":17,\"481210216133\":15,\"481210216372\":4}"`

As you can see the json string is a string of values type character. I need to pattern match the first column `TX_JAN_2019_DF$DEVICE[1]`, to see if the second column element `TX_JAN_2019_DF$DEVICE_HOME_AREA[1]` and the json string stored in that element contains the pattern and if it does, what is the number after the colon (307 for example in the first element).

Then of course do this for all columns `TX_JAN_2019_DF$DEVICE_HOME_AREA`

I'm at a loss on how to do this as the json adds a complication to normal pattern matching. I've looked at the jsonlite library, but the examples are not much help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please include a reproducible sample from your dataset to the question, i.e. the output from `dput(head(TX_JAN_2019_DF))` would be ideal. Right now you seem to describe 2 columns but use 3 different column names, `DEVICE`, `DEVICE_HOME_AREA`, `AREA` .  There are few other confusing bits, but there's a good chance that providing a data sample helps to clear those.

Comment: On top of that, what if it matches more than once in `DEVICE_HOME_AREA`? Print all matches?

Comment: It shouldn't match more than 1 time, the value after the colon is the number of times the pattern shows up.

Comment: @margusl, thank you for finding my typo. I was tired and not thinking. The first column should be TX_JAN_2019_DF$AREA not DEVICE. I have corrected this with edits. Also, I can paste the dput output, but there are 15k rows and more columns than in the example provided, and most of it is json in various columns.

Comment: @RoninUTA, we don't expect to get a  full dataset, just a minimal set to go with a description and for testing, in a reproducible form.  `head` in `dput(head(TX_JAN_2019_DF))`  limits it to 6 top rows.  The same goes for columns, If your question is only about 2 columns, a minimum reproducible example could just include that subset, e.g. `TX_JAN_2019_DF[1:5, c("AREA", "DEVICE_HOME_AREA")]`

Answer (score 2):

If I interpret your post correctly, this might be what you want:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# define dummy data
x <- "{\"481210216382\":307,\"481210216371\":50,\"481210216381\":43,\"481130137213\":35,\"481210216373\":27,\"481130137222\":21,\"481210216154\":21,\"481210216152\":17,\"481210216133\":15,\"481210216372\":4}"

TX_JAN_2019_DF <- tibble(
  AREA = c(481210216382, 42),
  DEVICE_HOME_AREA = c(x, x)
)

# define function to parse json and look up key
extract_value <- function(key, json) {
  dict <- as_vector(jsonlite::fromJSON(json))
  dict[as.character(key)]
}

TX_JAN_2019_DF |> 
  mutate(value = map2_int(AREA, DEVICE_HOME_AREA, extract_value))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>           AREA DEVICE_HOME_AREA                                            value
#>          <dbl> <chr>                                                       <int>
#> 1 481210216382 "{\"481210216382\":307,\"481210216371\":50,\"481210216381\…   307
#> 2           42 "{\"481210216382\":307,\"481210216371\":50,\"481210216381\…    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Keep in mind the comments by margusl and Andre Wildberg though.